# How to treat a comma as text in output?

Tags: postgresql

There's 1 column that contains commas. When I output my query to csv, these commas break the csv format. What I've been doing to avoid this is a simple
    replace(A."Sales Rep",',','')

Is there a better way of doing this so that I can actually get the commas in the final output without breaking the csv file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the fields with `"`

```
a,this has a , in it,b
```

would become

```
a,"this has a, in it",b
```

and if the fields have BOTH a `,` and a `"`, double the quotes:

```
a,this has a " and , in it,b
```

becomes

```
a,"this has a "" and , in it",b
```

Comment: +1.  Exactly, and then ensure that whatever process is *importing* these csv files knows how to *read* them properly.

Comment: Thanks, but if the query is something like select "Sales Rep" from Table1, how do I go about quoting fields?

Comment: not sure how postgres does it. mysql does have a "select into outfile" option which lets you specify the csv formatting/escaping options. if nothing else, you can quote everything with string replacement and concatenation in your query. `select '"' || fieldname || '"' etc...`

Comment: You want to check the docs for the "COPY" command. There's options to output CSV format with headers (or not) and copy a whole table or the result of a query. Note - "COPY" is executed server-side, to paths and permissions need to be viewed from that point - there is a psql version "\copy" that runs client-side.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) to get PostgreSQL to build the CSV for you:

> COPY -- copy data between a file and a table

Something like one of these:

```
copy your_table to 'filename' csv
copy your_table to 'filename' csv force quote *
copy your_table to stdout csv force quote *
copy your_table to stdout csv force quote * header
...
```

You have to be the super user to copy to a filename though. If you're inside `psql`, you can use the [`\copy` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> Performs a frontend (client) copy. This is an operation that runs an SQL COPY command, but instead of the server reading or writing the specified file, psql reads or writes the file and routes the data between the server and the local file system.

The syntax is pretty much the same:

```
\copy your_table to 'filename.csv' csv force quote * header
...
```